# Attach format to a pie chart xlsxwriter Python

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

have a pie chart defined here:

```
chart_1 = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'pie'})
chart_1.add_series({
    'name': 'Pie data',
    'categories': '=Sheet2!$A$1:$A$' + str(len(cat_count)),
    'values': '=Sheet2!$B$1:$B$' + str(len(cat_count)),
    'data_labels': {'value': True, 'leader_lines': True, 'name': 'georgia',
                    'font': {'size': 25, 'color': 'white', 'bold': True}},
})
```

I am trying to add some formatting , particularly a 'gerogia' font to the categories so they are uniform with the rest of my file

Answer (score 0):

You almost had the syntax correct apart from needing to set the `name` as part of the `font` sub-properties.

Here is a small working example:

```py
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('chart_pie.xlsx')

worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

worksheet.write_column('A2', ['Apple', 'Cherry', 'Pecan'])
worksheet.write_column('B2', [30, 30, 30])

chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'pie'})

chart.add_series({
    'name':       'Pie data',
    'categories': ['Sheet1', 1, 0, 3, 0],
    'values':     ['Sheet1', 1, 1, 3, 1],
    'data_labels': {'value': True,
                    'leader_lines': True,
                    'font': {'size': 25,
                             'name': 'georgia',
                             'color': 'white',
                             'bold': True}},
})

chart.set_legend({'font': {'name': 'georgia'}})

worksheet.insert_chart('C2', chart, {'x_offset': 25, 'y_offset': 10})

workbook.close()
```

**Output:**

[image]

Note also the somewhat easier programatic way of setting the range for the categories and values.

Comment: Applied what you suggested , it still hasn't changed the font for the pie charts key (the categories) in the chart to the needed font , would you be able to chow how to apply the font to the categories rather than the data_labels?

Comment: Do you mean to change the font in the chart legend? If so I've updated the example to add that via `set_legend()`.